# Doctrine orm Confusion with Symfony 2 generating entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, namespaces, filenames

This is my orm config for my Doctrine in Symfony2

```
orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes:  false
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                auto_mapping: false
                mappings:
                    MyMappings:
                        type: yml
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Bundle/Entity/orm
                        prefix: Bundle\Entity
```

My directory structure is set up like this:

- src

-- Bundle

--- Entity

---- orm

----- Bundle.Entity.(TableName).orm.yml

My question is why when I run:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyMappings
```

I would get the following exception:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyMappings

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                 
      Invalid mapping file 'Bundle.Entity.(TableName).orm.yml' for class 'Bundle\Entity\(TableName)'
```

the orm files were named `(TableName).orm.yml`

And the yml:

```
TableName:
    type: entity
```

When I used the import from database I added the namespace:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Bundle/Entity/orm --force --from-database --namespace="Bundle\\Entity\\"
```

which generated the Bundle.Entity.(TableName).orm.yml files.

And the yml:

```
Bundle\Entity\TableName:
    type: entity
```

Now, I keep getting

```
 [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                 
  Invalid mapping file 'Bundle.Entity.Bundle.Entity.(TableName).orm.yml' for class 'Bundle\Entity\Bundle\Entity\(TableName)'
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious as to how to properly generate these entities in the correct namespace. If I am not clear please let me know and I will try to rephrase this issue.

More Information:

- I am trying to generate these entities in a non-bundle namespace

Comment: I understand this is not a terrible useful answer, (hence comment) but I've always struggled when I've tried to move doctrine files away from the standard config of Bundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Entity.orm.yml

Comment: Can you update your answer with .yml (entire one) and corrispective entity?

Comment: Your use of (TableName) makes thing confusing.  I am assuming that you are not trying to use () as part of your entity name? Would have been better to use the actual code in your question.  So sitting in the orm directory is a file called "Bundle.Entity.(TableName).orm.yml"?  If so rename it to: TableName.orm.yml and that should fix your error.